# Understanding a certain sentence

Tags: sentence

Recently I read a book, since I'm not a native English speaker, this passage of sentence confuse me:

> If his face betrayed any hint of his disappointment at the explanation, ....

What's "betrayed" mean at this sentence? My interpretation is that it means his face "shows" hint of disappointment. Is it okay to interpret it like that?

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary?

Comment: You may want to also look at the study of microexpressions: http://www.scienceofpeople.com/2013/09/guide-reading-microexpressions/

Comment: I did some search about it in the dictionary, it just that this is the first time I've seen it being used in this way, so I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, "revealed" or "showed" as you said is the best interpretation but using "betrayed" gives a sense that it was out of the persons control and something that they didn't mean or want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It means

> If his face *gave away* any hint of his disappointment ...

But I would encourage you to look in a dictionary before asking.

Comment: I did some search about it in the dictionary, it just that this is the first time I've seen it being used in this way, so I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: @JohnStuart - I see what you mean.  (This would be helpful to include in a question!)

Answer (score 0):

The use of *betrayed* here emphasizes that the person is trying not to show any sign of disappointment. He's probably speaking or acting in a way that suggests he's not disappointed. If he doesn't control his facial expression carefully, then not only could it be interpreted as a sign of disappointment, but it would also reveal that his words and/or actions are false. This is a secret he does not wish to reveal, and *betrayal* is the act of neglecting someone's trust, e.g. by sharing a secret they've confided in you. Therefore the passage you quoted is personifying the man's face by suggesting it would reveal his secret - his true feelings - even though his face is a part of him and therefore something he inherently "trusts" to act according to his bidding.